# Birthday probability problem

Tags: probability, birthday

There are four people in a room, namely P, Q, R and S.

Q's birthday is different from everyone else. What is the probability that P and R share the same birthday?

---

I'm getting $1/364$ as answer.
$(365*364*1*364)/(365*364^3) = 1/364$

Comment: What does the presence of $S$ change to this problem?b

Comment: We may assume that $Q$ was born on December $31$, leaving the other $364$ days for the others. Whatever $R$'s birthday is, the probability $P$'s matches it is $1/364$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases: If $P$ and $R$ share same birthday, the number of choices $=364$, otherwise, the number of choices $=2{364\choose 2}=364*363$. Thus, the probability that $P$ and $R$ same birthday $=\frac{364}{364+364*363}=\frac{364}{364^2}=\frac{1}{364}$

Comment: While this is true, it is needlessly complicated.

Comment: i agree with you, but it's not so complicated and above that it's better to have solutions approached with different thoughts.

Comment: Sure, different approaches are good. I'd say that if you're going to involve ${364\choose 2}$, though, then it would be clearer to keep it in factorized form as $\frac{(364)(363)}{2}$ rather than multiplying it out. At a glance, it isn't obvious—at least not to me—that $132496 = 364^2$.

Comment: I too got $1/364$ but my teacher says its wrong. I guess he's wrong this time.

Answer (score 2):

If Q's birthday is different from everyone else's, then there are 364 choices for P and R. Thus, the probability that they are the same is indeed 1/364; the calculation need not be more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it is to fix P's birthday, and consider R. Since we know that neither of them share a birthday with Q, there are 364 different possibilities for R, each with equal probability. One of those possibilities is P's birthday, and thus the probability is 1/364.

Alternatively, you could just note that since neither share a birthday with Q, there are 364^2 ways to choose birthdays for P and R, 364 of which result in the two of them having the same birthday. Thus, the probability is 364/(364^2) = 1/364.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed need to be corrected for leap year, resulting in a slightly lower probability, $p=\frac{1}{364.2}$ instead of  $p=\frac{1}{364}$. My calculation follows.

In four consecutive years there are 3 years with 365 days and 1 year with 366 days, for a total $365*3+366=1461$ days. We have two possibilities for Q's birthday, Feb-29 with $p=\frac{1}{4061}$, and any other day of the year with $p=\frac{1460}{1461}$.

If Q's is Feb-29, then P and R have the other 365 days for a probability $p=\frac{1}{365}$, and the joint probability is $p=\frac{1}{1461}\frac{1}{365}$

If Q's is not on Feb-29, then P and R have each a probability of having birthdays on Feb-29 $p=\frac{1}{1460}$, and a probability of not having birthdays on Feb-29 $p=\frac{1}{364}$.

The joint probability is $p=\frac{1460}{1461}\left( \frac{1}{1460} \frac{1}{1460}+ \frac{1}{364}\right)$

Adding the two joint probabilities obtained, the result is $p=\frac{1}{1461}\frac{1}{365}+\frac{1460}{1461}\left( \frac{1}{1460} \frac{1}{1460}+ \frac{1}{364}\right) = \frac{1}{364.2}$